# Fluent NHibernate nullable one-to-one mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I've been trying to map two objects using a one-to-one bi-directional relationship. The relationship between the two objects is not required. Here are the objects:

```
public class Tenant
{
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
    public virtual int UnitId { get; set; }

    public virtual string UnitNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual int Rooms { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the mappings I'm trying to use:

```
public class Mappings : ClassMap<Unit>
{

    /*
     * Unit
     * ------------
     * UnitId (PK)
     * TenantId (FK)
     * Rooms
     * UnitNumber
     */

    public Mappings()
    {
        Id(x => x.UnitId).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References(x => x.Tenant);

        Map(x => x.Rooms).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UnitNumber).Not.Nullable();
    }
}



public class TenantMapping : ClassMap<Tenant>
{
    /*
     * Tenant
     * -------------
     * TenantId (PK)
     * Name 
     */
    public TenantMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.TenantId).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();

        HasOne(x => x.Unit).PropertyRef(x => x.Tenant);
    }
}
```

The expected table definitions are in the mapping comments. The tests that I'm using to verify the mappings are failing:

```
    [Test]
    public void SetTenantOnUnit()
    {
        int unitId = 0;
        int tenantId = 0;
        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var tenants = Builder<Tenant>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build();
            var unit = Builder<Unit>.CreateNew().Build();
            foreach(var tenant in tenants)  
                session.Save(tenant);

            session.Save(unit);

            unit.Tenant = tenants[3];
            tenantId = unit.Tenant.TenantId;
            session.SaveOrUpdate(unit);

            unitId = unit.UnitId;
        }

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var unit = session.Get<Unit>(unitId);
            Assert.That(unit, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(unit.Tenant, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(unit.Tenant.TenantId, Is.EqualTo(tenantId), "Incorrect Tenant Id");
        }

    }

    [Test]
    public void SetUnitOnTenant()
    {
        int tenantId = 0;
        int unitId = 0;
        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var tenant = Builder<Tenant>.CreateNew().Build();
            var units = Builder<Unit>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build();
            session.Save(tenant);

            foreach(var unit in units)
                session.Save(unit);


            tenant.Unit = units[3];
            unitId = tenant.Unit.UnitId;

            session.SaveOrUpdate(tenant);
            tenantId = tenant.TenantId;
        }

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var tenant = session.Get<Tenant>(tenantId);
            Assert.That(tenant, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(tenant.Unit, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(tenant.Unit.UnitId, Is.EqualTo(unitId), "Incorrect unit id");
        }
    }
```

I've included the source code here: https://bitbucket.org/crmckenzie/fluentnhibernate.discovery/overview

Ideally, I'd be able to create the relationship from either side and have it save successfully to the database. I've read the other one-to-one mapping topics on StackOverFlow, and none of them seem to be directly on point. How can I map this relationship correctly?

Answer (score 0):

your are missing a `session.Flush();` after `unitId = unit.UnitId;` and `tenantId = tenant.TenantId;` hence the assignement is not saved in db. The reason why the tenants and units are saved is that you force NHibernate to insert immediatly on `session.Save()`. Since you set `GeneratedBy.Identity()` nhibernate has to ask the database for the id, otherwise `unitId = unit.UnitId;` would yield the wrong result.